Why my code is showing time limit exceeded on leet code
Q. Given an integer array nums, return true if any value appears at least twice in the array, and return false if every element is distinct. (Full problem statement: https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/description/)
bool containsDuplicate(int* nums, int numsSize) {
    int i, j;
    int k = 0;
    int f = 0;
    for (i = k + 1; i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        if (nums[k] == nums[i])
        {
            f = 1;
            break;
        }

        if (i == numsSize - 1)
        {
            k++;
            i = k;
        }
    }

    if (f == 1)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}   

Why the above code is showing time limit exceeded on leetcode?
Please address the issue that might be related with the above code.
I was trying to check the conditions in only one loop without nesting them , but the code fails

Did you test your code (apart from running it on leetcode)? I suggest to add a main function, feed an array of values and debug your function.

@bodo the problem in this case isn't that the code is wrong per se, but rather one of algorithmic efficiency.

@Chris Maybe, but in general without a main function and input we cannot verify that the code does not contain errors that might lead to an endless loop.

You have basically turned a single loop into a nested loop with the following code. It would have been clearer just to write the nested loop.

        if (i == numsSize - 1)
        {
            k++;
            i = k;
        }


Explicit nested loops:
bool containsDuplicate(int* nums, int numsSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize - 1) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numsSize; j++) {
            if (nums[i] == nums[j])
                return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

This nested loop approach, whether written the way you have or explicitly with nested loops has a runtime complexity of O(n^2). This doesn't matter quite as much for very small arrays, but for bigger ones it's way too slow, and Leetcode will not only test with very small arrays, but they will use very big sample sizes specifically to test algorithmic issues like this.
Your code does perform very well if the duplicates are located very early in the sample array since it short-circuits, but Leetcode is unlikely to be so kind to you.
Instead, imagine you first sort the array (a good sort having O(n * log n) complexity) and then run a single O(n) loop over the sorted array to check for consecutive duplicates.
Comparing for different sample sizes we can see how poorly the approach you've taken scales. Clearly Leetcode probably won't ask your code to sort through an array with a billion integers, but a hundred or a thousand or ten thousand is perfectly reasonable and there's already a big difference at that scale.



n
n * log n
n^2
Comparison




10
33
100
~3x


100
664
10,000
~15x


1,000
9,966
1,000,000
~100x


10,000
132,880
100,000,000
~750x


100,000
1,661,000
10,000,000,000
~6,000x


1,000,000
19,930,000
1,000,000,000,000
~50,000x


10,000,000
235,230,000
100,000,000,000,000
~425,000x


100,000,000
2,657,500,000
10,000,000,000,000,000
~3,760,000x


1,000,000,000
29,900,000,000
1,000,000,000,000,000,000
~33,445,000x




Reducing the number of loops will not improve the time complexity if you still need to perform a huge number of operations. Even with only one loop, your code is O(N^2): it's just that all those iterations are now in a single loop.
You can find duplicates much more efficiently with data structures like hash sets (expected O(N) overall) or balanced binary search trees (O(N log N) overall).
C does not have any of these in its standard library, but you can use qsort to sort the array (there are no time complexity guarantees imposed by the standard, but it's usually O(N log N) at least on average). After sorting, duplicates can be trivially detected by checking pairs of adjacent elements.
int comp(const void* a, const void *b) {
    return *(int*) a - *(int*) b;
}
bool containsDuplicate(int* nums, int numsSize) {
    qsort(nums, numsSize, sizeof *nums, comp);
    for (int i = 1; i < numsSize; ++i) if (nums[i] == nums[i - 1]) return true;
    return false;
}


The expression *(int*) a - *(int*) b; suffers from possible arithmetic overflow, no?

@MikeNakis Not in the context of the problem, where all elements of nums are constrained to have absolute value at most 10^9.

Uh, I do not see such constraint in the description of the problem as provided by the OP.

@MikeNakis Full problem statement is here: https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/description/
